# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.(Subquery) Repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with this query. I want to do the next:

The records that aren't in the same table, should be add it using the other table.

```
DECLARE @account INT = 8825

INSERT INTO [Fleet].[dbo].[AccountsReports] ([AccountId], [ReportId], [ReportName])
    SELECT
        @account AccountId,
        [ReportId],
        [Name] 
    FROM
        [Fleet].[dbo].[Reports] 
    WHERE
        ReportId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,54) 
        AND ReportId NOT IN (SELECT @account AccountId, [ReportId], [Name] 
                             FROM [Fleet].[dbo].[Reports] 
                             WHERE ReportId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,54)
                            )
```

This shows an exception:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

The queries separated are working fine. Can you help me to learn what my problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you need to use `not exists` instead of `NOT IN`, because of `IN` only can compare one column value in the subquery.

If you want to compare multiple columns you can use `exists`

look like this.

```
insert into [Fleet].[dbo].[AccountsReports]
                            ([AccountId],
                            [ReportId],
                            [ReportName])
SELECT
    @account AccountId 
    ,[ReportId]
    ,[Name] 
FROM [Fleet].[dbo].[Reports] t1
where ReportId in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,54) and
not exists (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM [Fleet].[dbo].[Reports] t2
        WHERE t1.ReportId = t2.ReportId  and t1.Name = t2.Name
)
```

Comment: D-shih, thanks for your comment. Let me explain you to give you more information. The table contains reports identified by Id, the id's that aren't should be add with insert, your query is good.

Comment: @Ric_hc Ok I see I remove the condition.

Comment: Great D-Shih!!!!1 Exactly i needed.... Thanks my friend!!!

Comment: Just a note, with the ANSI SQL feature "_Row and table constructors_" `IN` can be used for several columns, e.g. `WHERE (t1.ReportId, t1.Name) IN (select t2.ReportId, t2.Name from t2)`. Although not supported by all dbms products. When it comes to `NOT IN`, its null value behavior is a bit tricky, so I'd recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead - just as in your answer.